# Partial classes or inheritance in controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

I'm creating an auth controller for three different user classes (SysAdmin, Admin, and User) and was wondering whether it would be better to create partial classes or use inheritance.

With a partial class I would make it like so:

```csharp
//file 1
[Authorize(Roles="SysAdmin")
public partial class AccountController { } //--> for sysadmin

//file 2
[Authorize(Roles="SysAdmin,Admin")
public partial class AccountController { } //--> for admin

//file 3
[Authorize(Roles="SysAdmin,Admin,User")
public partial class AccountController { } //--> for user
```

With a inheritance approach I would make it such that the `SysAminController` inherits from `AdminController` and `AdminController` inherits from `UserController`.

I'm a bit unsure on what the best solution would be and also how the `[Authorize]` annotations will work in the partial class example?

Essentially, I'm annotating the `AccountController` with

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User, Admin, SysAdmin")]
```

no matter what? Or am I annotating each specific file with different annotations?

Hope this makes sense.

I'm sort of new to this, so please don't give me too much hate ;-)

Comment: You should read [Favour composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#:~:text=To%20favor%20composition%20over%20inheritance,and%20creating%20a%20family%20tree.).

Comment: Why not simply have three different Controllers? When you somehow want to share code that is in the Controller it is likely that this code shouldn't be in the Controller in the first place.

Comment: @Ralf Yeah, as I mentioned in another comment, I just figured that having a 'shared' controller, the fetch methods in UI would be much easier to create by having one common controller and the 'routing names' would more or less be the same...

Comment: Don't know what fetch means in the context of an http API or what a UI has to do with it but how the routes look for the client is totally agnostic of the problem where and how the endpoints are implemented on the server. If you have a working solution with inheritance in your controllers and are going to change to individual controllers then the routes don't need to change. This change should not change anything for an already existing user of your http endpoints.

Comment: @Ralf It is relevant in terms of the naming of the controller and thereby the routing, which I know can be changed to whatever you like. So the client would not have to have to change the names of the fetch calls (the calls the API fyi)

Comment: Understood. Relying to much on "coding by convention" that is allowed here often leads to such problems. Trying to use that got you in to thinking of more complicated stuff like inheritance, partial classes etc. but to just not need to use something simple like a route attribute to be a little explicit on your endpoints?  Don't be to trustful on "coding by convention" it just looks like making things easy but most of the time it doesn't.

Comment: @Ralf Makes sense. I'll make it back to simple as possible, as recommended. Thanks for the clearance and help!

Answer (score 0):

Neither of them is needed. So I would go with the principle of "make it as simple as you can".

Use three different controllers.

All three roles have access to the `UserAccountController`. Only Admins and SysAdmins have access to the `AdminAccountController`. And only SysAdmins can access the `SysAdminAccountController`.

There is no need for any inheritance or composition or partial classes (which with the attributes on the class, will be a nightmare to understand and maintain).

If a SysAdmin wants to change their display name or add their preferred icon, they can go through the normal UserAccountController like everybody else.

Comment: Makes sense. I just figured that having a 'shared' controller, the fetch methods in UI would be much easier to create by having one common controller and the 'routing names' would more or less be the same...